# Can I merge branches in github even though i`m not a contributor?

Tags: github

I have a team working for my website and the thing is that my team leader does not reply to me anymore and I want to take things into my own hand. My question is how can I merge branches in my git repository even though i`m not a contributor?

Comment: Check out the repository and merge ist locally.

Comment: how can i merge it locally?

Comment: `git checkout main` to checkout your `main` branch and then merge the branch you want to merge, for example `git merge origin/feature/feature-1` to merge the `feature/feature-1` branch from your remote `origin`

Answer (score 0):

as long as you have right to push a merge commit in that branch you can merge it.